# How to relate "Product Backlog Item" with Shelveset?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tfs

I am trying to link my Shelveset to a Product Backlog Item.

The Shelveset is intended as a starting-Point for future implementation.

Obviously, in the Product BacklogItem I can "Link to":
[image: Link to in the links of the Product Backlog Item]

But there I miss the Option to link to the created Shelveset.

Availabel options are:

- Changeset
- Child
- Hyperlink
- Model Link
- Parent
- Predecessor
- Referenced By
- References
- Related
- Result Attachment
- Shared Steps
- Storyboard
- Successor
- Test Case
- Test Result
- Tested By
- Tests
- Versioned Item

Maybe I have to add some Configuration to TFS or the BacklogItem-Template...

Is there any Way to link to my Shelveset, or get some other relation between the Product Backlog Item and the Shelveset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **Description** or in **History** you can add a **Comment** with the name of the Shelveset.

You can also leave this Comment in a planed task like "Start with further investigation"

So you can easily find the appropriate Shelveset later.

I still see no way, to link the product Backlog Item direct to the Shelveset.